# FFMPEG Encoding MP4 for iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, html, video, ffmpeg

I am using the gem `streamio-ffmpeg` to convert an `.mp4` file to another `.mp4` file that conforms to iOS standards. I want to put that file in an HTML5 video tag. The video plays well on desktop and Android devices. However, no matter what I do, the iPad Mini 2 that I'm using will not play the video.

My options hash looks like this:

```
options = {video_codec: "libx264", resolution: "480x320", frame_rate: 30, video_bitrate: 500,
             x264_vprofile: "baseline", x264_preset: "slow", audio_codec: "aac", audio_bitrate: 56, aspect: 1.333333,
             audio_sample_rate: 44100, audio_channels: 1, custom: "-strict -2"}
```

When I load the new `.mp4` file back into `streamio-ffmpeg`, this is the object (and metadata) returned:

```
#<FFMPEG::Movie:0x007fb37b663ec0 
@path="/Users/ryan/workspace/videotest/app/assets/videos/video1-i.mp4",
@container="mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2", @duration=5.34, @time=0.02322,
@creation_time=nil,
@bitrate=1352, 
@rotation=nil, 
@video_stream="h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 1231 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)", 
@audio_stream="aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)",
@video_codec="h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661)", 
@colorspace="yuv420p", 
@video_bitrate=1231, 
@resolution="480x320",
@dar="3:2", 
@audio_codec="aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D)", 
@audio_channels="mono", 
@audio_bitrate=nil, 
@audio_sample_rate=44100>
```

I've tried just about everything I could find, with different bit rates, codecs, resolutions, etc. What are the correct options to play an `.mp4` on an iOS device?

BTW, `streamio-ffmpeg` allows pure `ffmpeg` options, so I'm ok with that.